# Lua comparing multiple integers

Tags: variables, if-statement, lua

I want to compare if n1-10 one of them is = box
then write  nx1 and ny1 and so on ... 
what could I do to compare them faster  . 
the below way will take years from me

```
 box=readString('[[[[[_name]+11c]+670]+394]+2fc]+1c',20)
    n1=readString('[_player]+184',20)
    n2=readString('[_player]+f94',20)
    n3=readString('[_player]+1da4',20)
    nx1= readInteger('[_player]+48d8')
    nx2= readInteger('[_player]+56e8')
    nx3= readInteger('[_player]+64f8')

    ny1= readInteger('[_player]+48dc')
    ny2= readInteger('[_player]+56ec')
    ny3= readInteger('[_player]+64fc')

    if box =n1 or n2 or n3   --lets say n1=box  
    then    writeInteger('[_player]+28c',n1x) 
            writeInteger('[_player]+28c',n1y) 

    if box =n1 or n2 or n3   --lets say n2=box  
    then    writeInteger('[_player]+28c',n2x) 
            writeInteger('[_player]+28c',n2y)
```

Answer (score 0):

You implementation is not good practive here. You'd better store these variable in to an array like

```
ns[1] = ...
ns[2] = ...
...
nys[1] = ...
nys[2] = ...
```

then

```
   key = -1
   for k,v in na do
     if box == v then
        key = k
     end
   end

   if key == -1 then
      print("no match values")
   else
      writeInteger('[_player]+28c',nys[key]) 
       writeInteger('[_player]+28c',nys[key])
   end
```